# Sort Data Frame in a List in R

Tags: r

Suppose that I have data frames named df1 to df20. These data frames are in a list.

The order of the data fame in the list is "df1", "df10", "df11", "df12",
How do I make it to become "df1", "df2", "df3", "df4", ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a vector of names and subset them. If the list is called `dflist`.

```
dflist <- dflist[paste0('df', 1:20)]
```

Can also use `gtools::mixedsort`.

```
dflist <- dflist[gtools::mixedsort(names(dflist))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Package `stringr` functions `str_sort` and `str_order` have an argument `numeric` that when set to `TRUE` sorts numerically. Here are two ways, assuming the data.frames list is named `dflist`.

```
dflist <- dflist[stringr::str_sort(names(dflist), numeric = TRUE)]

i <- stringr::str_order(names(dflist), numeric = TRUE)
dflist <- dflist[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the string *df* in the `names` of the `list` using `sub`, cast the result to *integer* using `as.integer` and use the output of `order` to get the wanted order in the `list`.

```
dflist <- dflist[order(as.integer(sub("df", "", names(dflist))))]
```

Alternatively you can remove all non digits using `\\D` in `gsub`.

```
dflist <- dflist[order(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", names(dflist))))]
```